# Public AND Protected notation on a single UML method?

Tags: uml

I was looking at an article which had a class diagram on it.
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method

In the section "Structure", you can find the diagram below.

[image]

The method compare() appears to be noted as both public and protected, but this doesn't really make sense and I've never seen it before. I would have written it off as a typo is it weren't consistent for all instances of the compare() method in the diagram.

Is there a special meaning for "+#" in a class diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typo error.

A NamedElement has 0..1 visibility.

"visibility : VisibilityKind [0..1]
Determines whether and how the NamedElement is visible outside its owning Namespace." p48

And to provide more explanation: NamedElement is one of the root classes of UML meta-model and Operation or Property inherit of NamedElement.

Comment: It might as well be that the `#` is part of the name (any language to accept that?). Anyhow, as stated only the `+` counts for visibility.

Comment: On the right there's the list of the methods (excluding sort() for some reason) and compare isn't preceded by #. It really does seem that it's just a typo, but it is kinda weird that the person made the same typo three times.

Comment: The explanation about the pattern does not refer to a language (I read quickly) and the norm says that you can get at most one visibility. Or this is mistake or this is a typo error. You choose but you can not define two visibilities.